# Carry out analysis when the source of PMOS and NMOS transistors are connected together

Tags: mosfet

I am trying to solve the following question:

[image]

I observed through calculation that both the transistors are in saturation region and hence carried out the analysis. But my answer is incorrect. Where have I gone wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Notice that if **Vin = 2.5V** the N channel will conduct only when **Vs < Vg - Vt = 2.5V - 1V = 1.5V** and the P-channel only when **Vs >Vg + Vt = 2.5V + 1V = 3.5V (Vdd = 2.5V)**. Therefore, for this given input voltage value only the N channel MOSFET can conduct current.  So, you must revisit your assumption that both transistors are conducting current.  And if we some math we will get  **Id= 0.104mA** Thus **Vo = +1.04V**. [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%3D+1%2F2*%28%282.5+-+x*10%29+-+1%29%5E2)